# How to read information from file .geojson in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I need help to read a polygon from a GeoJSON file, I know how to read
a simple point. This is the GeoJSON file and the Java code that I use
for read a point, now I need to read a polygon, someone can help me?

**GeoJSON file:**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.805694580078125,
          40.79717741518766
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              13.77685546875,
              40.823682398765996
            ],
            [
              13.77685546875,
              40.60300547512703
            ],
            [
              14.085159301757812,
              40.660847697284815
            ],
            [
              13.959503173828125,
              40.854851176469666
            ],
            [
              13.77685546875,
              40.823682398765996
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Java Code**

```
  case GeoJSON.TYPE_POINT:
    Point point=(Point) feature.getGeometry();
    double lat = point.getPosition().getLatitude();
    System.out.println(lat+"\n");
    double lon = point.getPosition().getLongitude();
    System.out.println(lon+"\n");
    GeoPoint x = new GeoPoint(lat,lon);
    mywaypoints.add(x);
    break;
```

Comment: Where is the java code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is my code Java, 
before i can't paste it.
<code>
case GeoJSON.TYPE_POINT:
                            Point point=(Point) feature.getGeometry();
                            double lat = point.getPosition().getLatitude();
                            System.out.println(lat+"\n");
                            double lon = point.getPosition().getLongitude();
                            System.out.println(lon+"\n");
                            GeoPoint x = new GeoPoint(lat,lon);
                            mywaypoints.add(x);
                            break;
</code>

Comment: Yeah, the code should not be in the comment but in the question itself in a "Code Sample"-block

Comment: i just added the java code to read the points from GeoJSON file